# DataTables regex search not working as expected for exact match

Tags: javascript, regex, datatables

I want to search a column of my DataTable for an exact value and return only the row that contains that value. I've read that the way to do this is to do a regex search for the specific value, however when I attempt this an exact regex search returns nothing.

For example in the following table I want to return only the row that contains an id=0

```
<table id="searchTable" class="formTable display dataTable" cellspacing="0" style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
            <td>London</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>London</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When the document is loaded I attempt to use the search api [as described here](http://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()).

```
var table = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    table = $('#searchTable').DataTable( {
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 5
    } );

table.columns(0).search('/0/',true,false).draw();

} );
```

[JS fiddle showing the regex failing](http://jsfiddle.net/y7rn6zyq/1/)

Comment: Maybe you just need to remove `'`s? `table.columns(0).search(/0/,true,false).draw();`. Note `^0$` will match for a `0` that is equal to a whole string. `/0/` will search for a `0` inside longer strings.

Answer (score 3):

The trick was to put the start character symbol '^' before the value being searched on and end character symbol '$' after the value. Without giving these two symbols the regex will always return nothing.

Fixed portion:

```
var table = null;
$(document).ready(function(){
    table = $('#searchTable').DataTable( {
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "iDisplayLength": 5
    } );

table.columns(0).search('^0$',true,false).draw();

} );
```

Comment: thanks! This was really helpful and saved me a lot of headaches :)

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody else face this problem. In my case the problem was related to searching for string characters that have special meaning in a regular expression (eg. "`AC (JLHA2) - GB/T1179-2008`" will give nothing even if the data exists in the table).

I was able to fix this by using `$.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex()` to escape all special characters.

Here is the fix:

```
var table = null;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        table = $('#searchTable').DataTable( {
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "iDisplayLength": 5
        } );

        // Escape the expression so we can perform a regex match    
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex('AC (JLHA2) - GB/T1179-2008');
        table.columns(0).search(val ? '^' + val + '$' ; '', true, false).draw();        
    } );
```